# Corrupt images and pdf with goldraccoon ftp-upload

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ftp

I use GoldRaccoon for ftp-upload in my iOS-Application. The filetransfer works perfekt with txt-files up to many mb size. But images and pdf-files would be corrupted when they be uploaded.

There is no error and the upload seems to be successfull.

When i look into the iPad in the folder of the application (with iExplorer), there the files are good. Its also equal how big the size of the image is. Also its equal if it is a jpg or a png.

Also the files all existing when I start the upload.

```
- (void)uploadFilesToFTP:(Objekt *)objekt withCsvFilePath:(NSString *)csvLocalFilePath {


__block typeof(self) bself = self;

[self.library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                            usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                                if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:self.albumName]) {
                                    InfoLogMy(@"found album %@", self.albumName);
                                    self.groupToAddTo = group;
                                }
                            }
                          failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {

                              UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fehler" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
                              [alertView show];
                              return;
                          }];


// dateien
InfoLogMy("Count of files %d", objekt.dateien.count);
for (Datei *datei in objekt.dateien)
{
    InfoLogMy(@"Upload starts");

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dateiPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:datei.dateiname];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dateiPath options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
    if( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dateiPath] )
    {
        if (!error) {

            if (datei.zimmer != nil) {

                // original image
                UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                __block typeof(self) bself = self;
                //Bild wird in das Photoalbum des iPads als Sicherung abgelegt.
                //Dies ist nicht mit PDF-Dokumenten möglich

                [self.library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[originalImage CGImage]
                                                  metadata:nil
                                           completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetURL, NSError* error) {
                                               if (error.code == 0) {

                                                   // try to get the asset
                                                   [self.library assetForURL:assetURL
                                                                 resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

                                                                     // assign the photo to the album
                                                                     [bself.groupToAddTo addAsset:asset];
                                                                 }
                                                                failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
                                                                    InfoLogMy("failed to retrieve image asset:\nError: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
                                                                }];
                                               }
                                               else {
                                                   InfoLogMy("saved image failed.\nerror code %i\n%@", error.code, [error localizedDescription]);
                                               }
                                           }];
            }

            // copy of image
            NSString *filenameCopy = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"copy-%@", datei.dateiname];
            NSString *localFilePathCopy = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filenameCopy];

            BOOL copyFileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localFilePathCopy];

            BOOL hasPaths = ([[datei.zeichnungen allObjects] count] > 0);
            BOOL hasSymbols = ([[datei.symbole allObjects] count] > 0);

            NSString *fileExtension = [datei.dateiname substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(datei.dateiname.length - 3, 3)];

            BOOL isPDF = ([fileExtension isEqualToString:@"pdf"]);

            if (copyFileExists == YES && (hasPaths == YES || hasSymbols == YES|| isPDF == YES)) {
                NSError *error;
                NSData *dataCopy = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:localFilePathCopy options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

                if (isPDF == NO) {
                    UIImage *copyImage = [UIImage imageWithData:dataCopy];

                    [self.library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[copyImage CGImage]
                                                      metadata:nil
                                               completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetURL, NSError* error) {
                                                   if (error.code == 0) {
                                                       InfoLogMy(@"saved image completed:\nurl: %@", assetURL);

                                                       // try to get the asset
                                                       [self.library assetForURL:assetURL
                                                                     resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

                                                                         // assign the photo to the album
                                                                         [bself.groupToAddTo addAsset:asset];
                                                                     }
                                                                    failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
                                                                        InfoLogMy(@"failed to retrieve image asset:\nError: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
                                                                    }];
                                                   }
                                                   else {
                                                       InfoLogMy(@"saved image failed.\nerror code %i\n%@", error.code, [error localizedDescription]);
                                                   }
                                               }];

                }


                if (!error) {

                    [self.requestsManager addRequestForUploadFileAtLocalPath:localFilePathCopy toRemotePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kFtpPathOutbox, filenameCopy]];

                }
            }
            else
            {

                //Wenn die Datei keine Zuordnung zu einem Zimmer hat.
                if (datei.zimmer != nil)
                {
                    [self.requestsManager addRequestForUploadFileAtLocalPath:dateiPath toRemotePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kFtpPathOutbox, datei.dateiname]];
                }
            }

        } else {
            // TO DO: Alert mit Fehler
            return;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        InfoLogMy(@"Datei existiert leider nicht");
        [Mbs writeLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Datei existiert nicht (%@)", datei.dateiname]];
    }
}

NSArray *parts = [csvLocalFilePath componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

NSString *remotePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kFtpPathOutbox, [parts lastObject]];

[self.requestsManager addRequestForUploadFileAtLocalPath:csvLocalFilePath toRemotePath:remotePath];

self.requestsManagerFailed = NO;

[self.requestsManager startProcessingRequests];
}
```

Comment: This looks like a problem with binary and ASCII modes of upload. When using ASCII mode the end of line characters (or bytes) in the data are automatically changed to a version compatible with the OS of the receiving system. This means that in non-text files random bytes might be changed, corrupting it.

Comment: Do you have a idea, where i can switch it with goldraccoon ?

Comment: No, I never used goldraccoon before. Maybe you can contact the developer? Good luck!